# Creating a dynamic array of an abstract class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic, abstract

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of an abstract class (CellPhone) and then fill it with different objects of type Cell1 and Cell2.

I tried with dynamic arrays and vectors but both give an error:

All classes are created and work, however in the main:

```
Cell1 c1("Orange", "Hello! This is your friend Rima, call me when you can.", 0777170, "Sony");
Cell2 c2("Zain", "Call me ASAP, Sam", 0777777777, "blue", "wifi");
Cell1 c3("Omnia", "Let me know when you can pass by", 0711111111, "Samsung");

CellPhone *c[3];

*c[0]=&c1;       //Conversion to base class error


vector<CellPhone*>  cp;
cp.push_back(&c1);      //Conversion to base class error
```

I've looked up other cases but both ways I'm getting an error? Why? And how to fix it?

EDIT:Here are the class headers for reference:

```
 class CellPhone{
  private:
     string branch, message;
     int phoneNumber;
 public:
    CellPhone(string, string, int);
    virtual void receiveCall() = 0;
    void receiveMessage();
    virtual void dial() = 0;
    void setBranch(string);
    void setMessage(string);
    void setPhoneNumber(int);
    string getBranch();
    string getMessage();
    int getPhoneNumber();
```

};

```
  #include "CellPhone.h"

 class Cell1:CellPhone{
 private:
     string cameraType;
     bool isCameraUsed;
 public:
     Cell1(string, string, int, string);
     void capture();
     void receiveCall();
     void dial();
     void setCameraType(string);
     string getCameraType();
```

};

```
 #include "Cell1.h"

 class Cell2:CellPhone{
 private:
      string wifi, bluetooth;
public:
     Cell2(string, string, int, string, string);
void turnBluetoothOn();
void turnBlueToothOff();
void setWifi(string);
void setBluetooth(string);
string getWifi();
string getBluetooth();
void receiveCall();
void dial();
```

};

Cell2 has the reference of Cell1 because if it didn't there would be a class redefinition error in the main.

Comment: Without CellPhone, Cell1, Cell2 definition, it's impossible to answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you do not choose an inheritance, C++ defaults to private inheritance. That's not prudent.

Comment: Also, your `CellPhone` class is missing the virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace class `Cell2 : CellPhone` by `class Cell2 : public CellPhone`.

Else, conversion from `Cell2` to `CellPhone` is not accessible (inheritance is `private` if unspecified).

Edit: As commented below, it's strongly recommended that you declare a virtual destructor for `CellPhone` class (that's recommended for any class you specialize at some point).

Comment: Also, it's 99% likely that you should be adding a virtual destructor to CellPhone.

Comment: @Frank: It is 100% likely, if you are storing derived objects in an array to base class pointers. Which the OP is.

Comment: That's only true if he deletes the objects from that vector, which is not the case since he creates the Cell objects on the stack. There are a few rare edge cases where a virtual destructor is not desired/waranted (and generally involves a protected destructor to avoid problems), but this is almost certainly not the case here.

Comment: @IInspectable: Only if you use the container to destroy the objects in the end. As posted by OP, objects are created on the stack as local variables, they will get destroyed nicely.

Comment: @jpo38 Why play with fire?  Just add a virtual destructor.  The current code, and any future code that has yet to be written will work correctly if the virtual destructor is added, not so if it is left out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Again: rare edge cases. There's a reason the language does not add that virtual destructor whenever it sees a virtual function.

Comment: @Frank Say that to the persons who have been saddled with a class that is meant to be derived from, want to use it polymorphically, and the author of the class left out the virtual destructor.  Happens more times than expected.